# loop through same variables in for loop

Tags: php, loops

How can I loop through each of these variable within a for loop?

```
 $prod1 = $_POST['Option1']; //get input text
 $prod2 = $_POST['Option2']; //get input text
 $prod3 = $_POST['Option3']; //get input text
 $prod4 = $_POST['Option4']; //get input text
    
 for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) { 
     $prod = $prod . $i;
 }
```

when I echo $prod . $i inside the loop, I want it to display the variable value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: `$_POST["Option$i"]`…!? Why assign them to individual variables in the first place?

Comment: Agreed with @deceze  .Directly use `$_POST` variable to print values.

Comment: In our case you can use `echo ${'prod'.$i};`. Not the best way, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be better off with storing your data in an array and then looping over the array:

```
 $products = [  
          $_POST['Option1'],
          $_POST['Option2'],
          $_POST['Option3'],
          $_POST['Option4']
  ];
    
 foreach ($products as $prod ) { 
     echo $prod;
 }
```

Alternatively, You can also iterate over the POST directly:

```
for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) { 
     echo $_POST['Option' . $i];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `$_POST` variable - it's an array.

```
foreach ($_POST as $prod)
{
  echo $prod;
}
```

(Obviously if there are other values in the `$_POST` array then you would need to check the key name first before deciding to use it.)

N.B. We don't know the source of this data (is it a HTML form) but it might make more sense for them to be submitted inside a single array to begin with - so all of the values would be accessed through `$_POST["options"]` for example, and you'd just loop through that specific list.